# Why the keras do not take my data from CSV

Tags: csv, tensorflow, keras

I am following the tutorial about import CVS data into tensorflow.
I followed every step.
How ever it does not works out.
It showed that one of my feature is not in the dictionary.
If so, how can i put it into dictionary
[The link to my colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h2xzaOZBescZ-wWOrtzyiQ40cTDVcM5C?usp=sharing)

The code is write below and the error information is written in the end

```
import functools

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_file_path = "/content/Productivity training.csv"
test_file_path = "/content/Productivity Testing.csv"

LABEL_COLUMN = 'Productivity'

def get_dataset(file_path):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_path,
    batch_size=12, 
    label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True)
return dataset

raw_train_data = get_dataset(train_file_path)
raw_test_data = get_dataset(test_file_path)

examples, labels = next(iter(raw_train_data)) # 第一个批次
print("EXAMPLES: \n", examples, "\n")
print("LABELS: \n", labels)


CATEGORIES = {
'over working hours': ['0', '2'],
'experience' : ['0.5', '0.75', '1'],
'absent' : ['0.5', '0.25', '0']
}

categorical_columns = []
for feature, vocab in CATEGORIES.items():
  cat_col = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key=feature, vocabulary_list=vocab)
  categorical_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(cat_col))


def process_continuous_data(mean, data):
# 标准化数据
data = tf.cast(data, tf.float32) * 1/(2*mean)
return tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])

MEANS = {
'Weekday' : 4,
'highest' : 9.2540,
'lowest' : 3.47,
'Weather' : 2.63,
'Wind speed': 2.31
}

numerical_columns = []

for feature in MEANS.keys():
  num_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature, normalizer_fn=functools.partial(process_continuous_data, MEANS[feature]))
  numerical_columns.append(num_col)

preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(categorical_columns+numerical_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  preprocessing_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
train_data = raw_train_data
test_data = raw_test_data


model.fit(train_data, epochs=20)
```

Here is the error info:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
```

--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
978             else:
979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:389 call
    outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/feature_column/dense_features.py:169 call  **
    self._state_manager)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2592 get_dense_tensor
    return transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2355 get
    transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2564 transform_feature
    input_tensor = transformation_cache.get(self.key, state_manager)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2339 get
    raise ValueError('Feature {} is not in features dictionary.'.format(key))

ValueError: Feature Weather is not in features dictionary.
```

Comment: Very well composed question. You might want to add a sample from your training and testing CSV files, because there is always room for errors in CSV :)

Comment: Thank you for your concern. This is the link of the CSV file. @Burhan Ali
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SHr2IJIcWRHcyT2UpHB-nN53pMhO40DJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems case issue, Can you try as `MEANS = { 'Weekday' : 4, 'highest' : 9.2540, 'lowest' : 3.47, 'weather' : 2.63, 'Wind speed': 2.31 }`. Thanks!